# npm request module: pass login to access route

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, passport.js

Assume the following RESTful scenario:

service 1 wants to create a new item in the database of service 2. Unfortunately service 2 is behind a login route (npm passport module).
Service 1 needs to pass/hop over the login route to reach the route for creating this item (post /items/).

**My question is now:**
Do I first need to access the /login/ route with its credentials to then proceed with the routes behind it? 
When I use the browser webapp version, the browser stores the cookie after logging in. Then I can click a "create new item" button to store it in the DB.

But how can I tell my javascript code that, after logging in I am still the valid user? This is really not clear to me.

I intentially did not post any code snippets yet, because first I need to understand it.

I hope this is a more usual "problem" others also had before.

Many thanks!

Comment: You need to take the cookie from the login route and send it with the items request, just like the browser do.

Answer (score 0):

The answer you are looking for is JWT (JSON Web Tokens). when logging in, your REST API should return a JWT. And the frontend should use that JWT to call the other REST API endpoints. For more information on how to use these in a NodeJs environment, you can check the following articles.

1. https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-anatomy-of-a-json-web-token
2. https://scotch.io/tutorials/authenticate-a-node-js-api-with-json-web-tokens

The internet is filled with guides about JWT. Just read some of them for the actual implementation details.

Comment: Okay great thanks so far! These links definitely help to get into this topic!

Comment: If you find the answer satisfactory, please mark it as the answer.